# Test FTP connection with PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I am using the PHP script below to test FTP connections.  Currently it is printing an array of the files, if it successfully connects.

How can I get it to also display a message, if it is able to connect?  Like 'Connection Successful'.

```
$con = ftp_connect($server) or die("Couldn't connect"); 
ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
ftp_close($con);
```

**EDIT**

I have it working now but, I've tested this on a few domains I have on a MediaTemple server and they all seem be timing out. Yet, it works with all other domains I have tried. Are their servers blocking the request?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Simply do a check if `ftp_nlist()` is an array.

Like:

`echo is_array(ftp_nlist($con, ".")) ? 'Connected!' : 'not Connected! :(';`

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nlist.php

Comment: Thanks, that works great :) .  However, I've tested this on a few domains I have on a MediaTemple server and they all seem be timing out.  Yet, it works with all other domains I have tried.  Are their servers blocking the request?

Comment: @Batfan -- could be, however try `mr.w`'s answer below, as he included a try / catch statement that will give you the `$e->getMessage();` if there is an error, offering some insight into what happened (timout / invalid authentication, etc).

Comment: Hmmm, I tried Mr. W's script and it still failing on the MediaTemple hosted domains, with no error being displayed.

Comment: There is a better way. `if(!$con){echo "Not connected.";}`

Answer (score 28):

Both ftp_connect() and ftp_login() return a boolean indicating success. Thus, something like this should do what you want, if I'm interpreting properly:

```
try {
    $con = ftp_connect($server);
    if (false === $con) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }

    $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
    if (true === $loggedIn) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
    }

    print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
    ftp_close($con);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: In my case `ftp_login` throws a warning. Maybe it depends on php settings.

Answer (score 6):

Hey.  I'm new here so maybe posting this late answer is not welcome, but it may help people in the future.

The reason why it's not working with MediaTemple is because they only accept passive connections.

After logging in with `ftp_login()`, simply call `ftp_pasv($ftp, TRUE);` and you'll be set.

Comment: Comment is definitely welcome.  Thanks for the info :)  I'll have to give that a whirl.

Answer (score 3):

Hello I have tried this..Working properly.

```
set_time_limit(300);//for setting 
$path='/'.date('dmY').'';
$ftp_server='';
$ftp_server_port="";
$ftp_user_name='';
$ftp_user_pass="";

// set up a connection to ftp server
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $ftp_server_port); 
// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// check connection and login result
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
    echo "Fail</br>";
} else {
    echo "Success</br>";
    // enabling passive mode
    ftp_pasv( $conn_id, true );
    // get contents of the current directory
    $contents = ftp_nlist($conn_id, $path);
    // output $contents
    var_dump($contents);
}

// close the FTP connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

Answer (score 3):

While I agree with the logic in the accepted answer from @Jakub of calling `ftp_nlist()` and testing data type with `is_array()`, this can be very slow and cumbersome with particularly large, bloated ftp directories like the ones I am currently working on. And I don't like the idea of creating a blank directory just for testing, which can be renamed/removed later as considered to be unneeded, perhaps by another developer or because you forgot what it was placed there for.

I am using a passive ftp connection, so for my purpose on cron scripts that can take a long time to execute and potentially require reconnection, I detect using this:

```
function check_connection_status($conn_id) {
    return ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
}
```

Issuing a fresh call to `ftp_pasv()` will make no alteration to the state of the ftp connection, but it will respond true if the connection is active and logged in/false if not so you can program to reconnect again :)

Answer (score 2):

Note that you're already `die`ing when you fail to connect, so you can assume that you are connected. However, you can also check the status of the connection using:

```
echo $con !== FALSE ? 'Connected' : "Couldn't connect";
```

> ftp_connect: Returns a FTP stream on success or FALSE on error.