# error upon uploading image no such path or directory

Tags: php, forms

Good day, I have been following a tutorial and have worked really hard to make this script work, I have managed to fix many things however the one constant problem I'm getting is:

*`No such file or directory in /home/xxxxxxx/public_html/regForm.php on line 93`*

What I am trying to acomplish is get user to upload a profile pic to my live server / website upon registration, here is part of my form and the code below:

I would greatly appreciate it if a more experienced user can give it a scan and advise to where I am going wrong, thanx in advance

**HTML FORM**

```
 <form ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data" name="registration-form" id="regForm" method="post" action="regForm.php">
 :
 :
Upload Picture: <INPUT NAME="file_up" TYPE="file">
<input type="submit"  value="Register" name="register" class="buttono" />
</form>
```

**UPLOAD SCRIPT**

```
$file_upload="true";
$file_up_size=$_FILES['file_up']['size'];
echo $_FILES['file_up']['name'];

if ($_FILES['file_up']['size']>250000){
    $msg=$msg."Your uploaded file size is more than 250KB
 so please reduce the file size and then upload.<BR>";
$file_upload="false";
}

if (!($_FILES['file_up']['type'] =="image/jpeg" OR $_FILES['file_up']['type'] =="image/gif"))
{
    $msg=$msg."Your uploaded file must be of JPG or GIF. Other file types are not allowed<BR>";
$file_upload="false";
}

$file_name=$_FILES['file_up']['name'];

if($file_upload=="true"){

$ftp_server = "xxxxxx";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$ftp_username='xxxxxx';
$ftp_userpass='xxxxxx';
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_username, $ftp_userpass);

$file = $file_name;

// upload file
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "public_html/img/userPics", $file, FTP_ASCII)) //here is the problem with the path I suspect
  {
  echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Error uploading $file.";
  }

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);   
}
```

Comment: yep. Use a binary method `FTP_BINARY` http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php and make sure the path is correct and that the folder has the right permissions to write to it. Use error reporting also.

Comment: You might even have to use the full system path `/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/userPics/` you did forget a slash though in `public_html/img/userPics` which should be `public_html/img/userPics/` otherwise it's going to look for a folder called `userPicsIMAGE.JPG` rather than  `userPics/IMAGE.JPG`

Comment: I'm pretty sure my comments above will solve this.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thank you for your comment what I dont get is should I make the path `www.mywebsite.com/public_html/img/user_pics` or should I use the path im using in script above, very silly question but how do I know if im using the right path or not?

Comment: You're welcome. I made an edit to my second comment. *should I make the path www.mywebsite.com/public_html/img/user_pics* - no. See my edited comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- got it going to give it a try and let you know...thanks a million

Comment: You're welcome Marilee. Now, you may have to play around with the paths. If running from the root, something like `$ftp_conn, "img/userPics/"...` or `$ftp_conn, "../img/userPics/"...` or as I stated above `/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/userPics/`. Doing it with FTP is a bit tricky. One works for some, while it won't for others. I've seen this happen a few times. Don't forget the trailing slash.

Comment: I've posted an answer for you below and have added a few things, should you have already seen it. That's the best I can do, in order to hopefully solve this Marilee.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with images, you need to use a binary format.

FTP_BINARY instead of FTP_ASCII.

As per the manual:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php

Make sure the path is correct. This can differ from different servers.

You also need a trailing slash here:

```
public_html/img/userPics/
                        ^
```

Otherwise, your system will interpret that as:

`userPicsIMAGE.JPG` rather than the intended `userPics/IMAGE.JPG`

Yet, you may need to play around with the path itself. FTP is a bit tricky that way.

I.e.:

- `/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/userPics/`
- `img/userPics/`
- `../img/userPics/`

Depending on the file's area of execution.

```
Root > ftp_file.php  
-img  
   -userPics
```

The folder also needs to have proper permissions to be written to.

- Usually 755.

  Use error reporting if your system isn't already setup to catch and display error/notices:

  - http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

An example from the FTP manual:

```
<?php 
ftp_chdir($conn, '/www/site/'); 
ftp_put($conn,'file.html', 'c:/wamp/www/site/file.html', FTP_BINARY ); 
?>
```

Another thing though, the use of of "true" and "false". You're most likely wanting to check for truthness

```
$file_upload=true;
```

rather than a string literal `$file_upload="true";`

same thing for

```
if($file_upload=="true")
```

to

```
if($file_upload==true)
```

and for `$file_upload="false";` to check for falseness

to `$file_upload=false;`

Read the manual on this:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

> This is the simplest type. A boolean expresses a truth value. It can be either TRUE or FALSE.

---

Test your FTP connection, pulled from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3729769/

```
try {
    $con = ftp_connect($server);
    if (false === $con) {
        throw new Exception('Unable to connect');
    }

    $loggedIn = ftp_login($con,  $username,  $password);
    if (true === $loggedIn) {
        echo 'Success!';
    } else {
        throw new Exception('Unable to log in');
    }

    print_r(ftp_nlist($con, "."));
    ftp_close($con);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Failure: " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

Naming conventions:

I also need to note that on LINUX, `userPics` is not the same as `userpics`, should your folder name be in lowercase letters.

Unlike Windows, which is case-insensitive.