# unexplained syntax error when adding string to variable

Tags: php

Im adding a string of a path to a variable, its pretty basic. Please see my image below:

**The Problem**

```
$target_dir = "C\wamp\www\test\img\userPics";
```

This above code works with no syntax errors BUT when I add a last backslash to the end of the string like so:

```
$target_dir = "C\wamp\www\test\img\userPics\";
```

I get all the syntax errors as you can see in image below.

Can anyone please explain to me why Im getting this error **when adding a slash to the string** as you can see on line 65?

[image]

Comment: You appear to be escaping the quote at the end

Comment: curious: did you pull that from the example I left in my answer for your other question?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I did. Im still battling to get the image uploaded  so now Im first trying to upload it to my testing server but still no luck :-(

Comment: try `"C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\img\\userPics\\";` or see the answer below.

Comment: did error reporting reveal anything for the other one, and using your existing syntax along with my suggestions?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I think you have to face the fact that no one has ever heard of this crazy `error_reporting()` you keep suggesting...

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm just weird that way ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Who would ever want to know they made an error?? It's not human nature to admit fallibility.

Comment: comment was deleted about my not mentioning about the trailing slash.. [I did here...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389616/error-upon-uploading-image-no-such-path-or-directory#comment52648321_32389616) and in my answer ;-)

Comment: @Rasclatt I will admit this: I am way past my bedtime. Time to hit the hay, *ciao for now*.

Comment: Ahhh benissimo!!! you're welcome. now which one, this one and using `"C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\img\\userPics\\";` or the other question? @Marilee

Comment: @Fred-ii- good night and see ya.

Comment: @Rasclatt I'm just waiting to see if Marilee wants me to post an answer for this. *Yawn* if what I said about using the escaping method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Don't do it...then you will go onto another question while waiting for the response and the cycle will continue...soon the sun will come up.

Comment: @Rasclatt I know the feeling. Then I'd have to make a few more cappuccinos.

Comment: @Rasclatt I decided to post after all. I'll let Marilee decide. Ok... I am "really" gone now. *arrivederci!* cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- Ok for reals...later...stop editing your post... :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing you're wanting to run this on a Windows platform, you need to use an escaped method:

```
"C:\\wamp\\www\\test\\img\\userPics\\";
```

along with the escaped trailing slash.

Comment: I am now off to lah lah land.

Answer (score 0):

is should come as

```
$target_dir = "C/wamp/www/test/img/userPics/";
```

Change this `\` to this `/`

But without pointing Full path use [`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Read this as well

1. [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
2. [Backslash in PHP — what does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10788400/backslash-in-php-what-does-it-mean)
3. [Document Root PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927968/document-root-php)

Comment: actually, they can use \ just as long as it's used as `c:\\wamp\\www\\...` if on a Windows server.